# How to extend function declaration defined by DefinitelyTyped community?

Tags: typescript, types, definitelytyped

I'm using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) library within TypeScript project. Together with this library, I've imported [@types/jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jsonwebtoken) library to provide types. 
Within this library jsonwebtoken's function `verify` [declared as following](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/288692b272b695eda00a47f93339e1e16ee756b1/types/jsonwebtoken/index.d.ts#L162):

```
export function verify(
  token: string, 
  secretOrPublicKey: Secret, 
  options?: VerifyOptions
): object | string;
```

But I would like to specify which object exactly it returns, not just `object | string` for example, an object defined by the following interface:

```
export interface DecodedJwtToken {
  userId: string;
  primaryEmail: string;
}
```

How can I achieve it within my project? Can it be done without type conversion, i.e.

```
const decodedToken: DecodedJwtToken = verify(token, JWT_PRIVATE_KEY) as DecodedJwtToken;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [module augmentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
import { Secret, VerifyOptions } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export interface DecodedJwtToken {
    userId: string;
    primaryEmail: string;
}

declare module 'jsonwebtoken' {
    function verify(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions): DecodedJwtToken;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I have been looking for